# checking uniform convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have a doubt in a question in which I need to check the uniform convergence of the series given by:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$$ on (-$1,1$)

Now if the series is uniformly convergent,then its sequence of partial sums (s$_n$) is uniformly convergent.

I have found that $s$$_n$ = $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$  which point-wise converges to $s$($x$) =  $\frac{1}{1-x}$

If ($s$$_n$) is uniformly convergent ,then $\sup${$\lvert s_n(x)-s(x)\rvert$:$x$ $\in$($-1,1$)| should tend to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Now how to check whether $\sup${$\lvert $$\frac{x^n}{1-x}\rvert$:$x$ $\in$($-1,1$)} converges to zero as $n$ tends to infinity or how can I  use the definition here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supremum is $+\infty$ for all $n$, because
$$\lim_{x \to 1-0}\frac{x^n}{1-x}=+\infty$$
The best you can do is uniform convergence on $[-a, a]$ for all $a \in (0, 1)$, with the Weierstass M-test, for example.

Comment: What are you saying about the M-test?

Comment: @Gitika You can prove that the series is uniformly convergent on $[-a, a]$ for $a \in (0, 1)$ with the M-test.

Comment: You can use cauchy hadamard or the ratio test if you dont like the M test.

Comment: @Botond..with which series should I compare to apply the M- test?

Comment: @Gitika Well,if $|x|\leqslant a$ then we have that $|x^n|=|x|^n\leqslant a^n$, and $\sum_{n} a^n$ is convergent if $0<a<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Each partial sum of the series is bounded. If the series converged uniformly on $(-1,1),$ then the sum would be bounded there. But the sum is $\dfrac{x}{1-x},$ which is unbounded as $x\to 1^-.$